# How to get rid of extra space after multicol environment?

Tags: spacing, multicol

I have a problem of extra-space after `multicol` environment. I am trying to create a small form; here is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{fontspec} %
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english} 
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \noindent 
    \textbf{Procurement \textnumero:}  \dotfill \\
    {} \\
    \textbf{Procurement date:}  \dotfill \\
    {} \\
    \textbf{Shipment type:}  \dotfill \\ 
    \vfill\null
    \columnbreak
    \noindent \textbf{Received by:}  \dotfill \\
    {} \\
    \textbf{Received on date:} \dotfill \\
    {} \\
    \textbf{COuntry of origin:} \dotfill \\
\end{multicols} %\par
\begin{center}
    \begin{shaded}
        \Large \textbf{\textsc{Exemplary Specimen:}}
    \end{shaded}
\end{center} \par 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

There is way too much space after 2-columns environment! It eats valuable space, as I want my form to fit within 1 page! I think I tried to use `\setlength\multicolsep{0pt}`, but with no effect! Any hints are welcomed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides some clearer code that reproduces the output, but with options to play around with the spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{cfr-lm,lipsum,tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup\bfseries
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} X X @{} }
  Procurement \textnumero: \dotfill &
    Received by: \dotfill \\ \\
  Procurement date: \dotfill &
    Received on date: \dotfill \\ \\
  Shipment type: \dotfill &
    Country of origin: \dotfill
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{2\baselineskip}% Adjust to suit your needs

\noindent
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X }
  \cellcolor{shadecolor}\centering\Large Exemplary Specimen:
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\bigskip% Adjust to suit your needs

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

You can also just use the `article` class, shrink the base font size and then use [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) to allow more real estate on your page. Something like, say

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2in]{geometry}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Werner! In essence, you decided NOT to use multicols, but instead use tabular environment, am I right? I was thinking about this approach as well, but decided to check if there is an easy fix for multicol. P.S. I used 14pt font for sake of my eyes, in original document it will be 12pt, of course. Anyway, thanks for the remark!

Comment: @user136555: Yes. You don't need a natural flow of content from one column to the next; your document content works well with a `tabular`-like structure.

Comment: Note that `\vspace` also accepts negative values, so you can use that in order to reduce vertical spacing), e.g. `\vspace{-1\baselineskip}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `\\` for “leaving a blank line”. In this case, you can set locally an increased baseline skip.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.64, 0.64, 0.82}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\textbf{Procurement \textnumero:} \dotfill

\textbf{Procurement date:} \dotfill

\textbf{Shipment type:} \dotfill

\textbf{Received by:} \dotfill

\textbf{Received on date:} \dotfill

\textbf{Country of origin:} \dotfill
\end{multicols}

\begin{shaded}
\centering\Large\bfseries Exemplary Specimen:
\end{shaded}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Note that `cfr-lm` does nothing when `fontspec` is loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I simply put a command like

```
\vspace{-0.5cm}
```

after "\end{multicols}" to "remove" the extra space and I am happy with the result.